# Is selenium 3.12 and geckodrvier 0.21.0 are compatible and stable, all tests gets skipped on linux machine

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Platform details:

> geckodriver 0.21.0 , Firefox: 60, Selenium: 3.12, cent Os 7

When i ran it using mvn it starts successfully:

> geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:14185
>
> Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 284135

Tests run successfully on windows machine however when running the same on CentOs 7, tests gets skipped.

I observed All tests get skipped as the GUI of Firefox gets closed after some time with below info and error on cmd console:

> INFO: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException:
>   unexpected end of stream on Connection{localhost:33365, proxy=DIRECT
>   hostAddress=localhost/12  6.10.0.1:258107
>
> [ERROR] java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:2285
>
> /bin/sh: line 1:  8780 Killed
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java

```
if(platform.equalsIgnoreCase("linux")) {
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
DesiredCapabilities desiredCap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir",System.getProperty("user.dir")+ File.separator + "target");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/path/geckodriver/geckodriver");
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","/usr/bin/firefox/firefox");
desiredCap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,Platform.LINUX);
desiredCap.setCapability("webdriver.firefox.profile",DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

I have spent so much time on this but unable to find the root cause of this.
Using maven surefire plugin 2.19.1.

Kindly help me on this i am really stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.

Check for all the processes being used in your automation, make sure multiple processes are not running. Most importantly for following:

```
ps -ef|grep firefox

ps -ef|grep geckodriver

ps -ef|grep java
```

**Close if multiple process are running**

Check for any error logs:

```
sudo vi /var/log/messages
```

Find for Kill or ERROR.This should help where it is breaking.

Comment: Thanks @vish, Yes it was showing multiple processes running. I killed all processes and when ran it again it has permanently fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation below the combination of the binaries which you have mentioned in your question (**Selenium v3.12** / **GeckoDriver v0.21.0** / **Firefox v60**) are compatible and stable as follows:

[image: Geckodriver Releases]

This error message...

```
INFO: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{localhost:33365, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=localhost/12 6.10.0.1:258107
[ERROR] java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:2285
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

As you have mentioned about using *GeckoDriver v0.21.0* there is no need to mention the `setProperty` with **`webdriver.firefox.bin`**. You need to ensure that *Mozilla Firefox* is installed at the default location for each system.

### Solution

- As per your *code trials*  though you have created and configured the `FirefoxOptions` Class and `DesiredCapabilities` Class objects, you havn't passed them during initializing the *WebDriver*.
- If your *usecase* requires the `FirefoxOptions` Class and `DesiredCapabilities` Class objects you need to pass them during initializing the *WebDriver* and *Web Browser*.
- If your *usecase* **does not** requires the `FirefoxOptions` Class and `DesiredCapabilities` Class objects you need to remove them.

Comment: Same issue has started coming again. don't know what's going wrong :(